# Sum multiple items with multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, array

Given the following table, let's say I want to sum the New York "ACT" sales in Q2.

[image]

The answer would be 59. How do I do that with a formula?

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.

Comment: Please do not edit a question to ask a new question, It invalidates the answers given.  Ask a new question instead.

Comment: sorry. i posted another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$3:$A$8 = "New York")*($C$1:$F$1 = "Q2")*($C$2:$F$2 = "ACT")*$C$3:$F$8)
```

[image]

Another formula that does the same thing:

```
=SUM(INDEX(($A$3:$A$8 = "New York")*($C$1:$F$1 = "Q2")*($C$2:$F$2 = "ACT")*$C$3:$F$8,))
```